# How do I make text appear then disappear then another text appear when someone taps a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A while ago I found this picture on the internet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDRj5.jpg

(Sorry about the bad word, albeit I blurred it)

And I liked the way they forced people to read the terms

So I decided to make something like it on my website for applying for staff in a game

But my poor knowledge in coding isn't enough to do that by my own

So I need your help

I want this to happen:

People open the page, a timer starts counting

If they don't want to read the terms they scroll down to "apply" straight away

If they tap apply while the timer that started counting is less than 10 minutes

The button will disappear and will show:

"You can't just read the whole terms within x (the time that passed during the moment s/he opened that page and the moment s/he pressed apply)!

You need atleast 10 minutes to read it!

You are either a robot or an alien, because no one can read that fast!

Sorry but we don't need robots or aliens in our staff team, we need humans.

The apply button will unlock in:

(The time left for the 10 minutes to finish)"

And when the time is up the timer disappears and the apply button that disappeared shows up again but this time it has the link to the application page.

It would be really appreciated if you help me with that

Also it would be more appreciated if you write the full code, not just saying what coding language to use and/or what plugin to use.

Comment: 10 minutes is 10 lifetimes in internet time. The average attention span of someone browsing the web is that of a 4 year old.

Comment: It is indeed but it's important to read terms, if they are not patient enough to read them, how will the bear being a staff?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not looking for HTML but for JavaScript. I’m on my phone right now so I cannot really help but don’t expect people to give you the code, you should try by yourself. Actually you could find it searching on google for session in JavaScript, cookies, timer...

Good luck anyway and best wishes